# Select each item of ListView one by one with arrow keys

Tags: flutter, dart

Basically, what I'm trying to achieve is a search bar like the one YouTube has where you can select through the search results one by one with arrow keys.

I tried playing around with `FocusNode`, but I can't to seem my head around it.

Comment: is this for flutter web?

Comment: Not specifically for web. I'm trying to build a cross-platform app including web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please give this code a shot, It's a highly customizable search bar from the Flutter framework itself. It also covers shifting the focus from one element to other elements.
**Note: I checked it on the web only.**

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Search Bar with Suggestions'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: SearchBar(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SearchBar extends StatefulWidget {
  const SearchBar({super.key});

  @override
  _SearchBarState createState() => _SearchBarState();
}

class _SearchBarState extends State<SearchBar> {
  TextEditingController _searchController = TextEditingController();
  FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();
  int _selectedIndex = -1;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _focusNode.addListener(() {
      if (_focusNode.hasFocus) {
        setState(() {
          _selectedIndex = -1;
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: Autocomplete<String>(
        optionsBuilder: (TextEditingValue textEditingValue) {
          return _suggestions
              .where((String suggestion) =>
              suggestion.toLowerCase().contains(textEditingValue.text.toLowerCase()))
              .toList();
        },
        onSelected: (String selectedValue) {
          print('Selected: $selectedValue');
        },
        fieldViewBuilder: (BuildContext context,
            TextEditingController controller,
            FocusNode focusNode,
            VoidCallback onFieldSubmitted) {
          _focusNode = focusNode;
          _searchController = controller;
          return TextField(
            controller: controller,
            focusNode: focusNode,
            onChanged: (String value) {
              // Add any additional logic when text changes
            },
            onSubmitted: (String value) {
              // Add any logic when the user submits the search
              onFieldSubmitted();
            },
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
              hintText: 'Search',
            ),
          );
        },
        optionsViewBuilder: (context, onSelected, options) {

          return Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
            child: Material(
              elevation: 4.0,
              child: ConstrainedBox(
                constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 200),
                child: ListView.builder(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: options.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    final String option = options.elementAt(index);
                    return InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        onSelected(option);
                      },
                      child: Builder(
                          builder: (BuildContext context) {
                            final bool highlight = AutocompleteHighlightedOption.of(context) == index;
                            if (highlight) {
                              SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((Duration timeStamp) {
                                Scrollable.ensureVisible(context, alignment: 0.5);
                              });
                            }
                            return Container(
                              color: highlight ? Theme.of(context).focusColor : null,
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                              child: Text(option),
                            );
                          }
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
    
      ),
    );
  }

  final List<String> _suggestions = [
    'Flutter',
    'Dart',
    'Widgets',
    'YouTube',
    'Search',
    'Example',
  ];
}
```